# Multiwire Branch Circuit with GFCI

Tags: electrical, gfci

I recently added some ceiling lights and had to tap into an existing junction box that had a 3 wire multiwire branch circuit run to it.  This is a kitchen GFCI receptacle.  The red wire is on a breaker that runs to the dishwasher/garbage disposal.  The black wire fed the GFCI (all share neutral and ground).  I pigtailed off the black to feed power to the lights.  My question is should all neutrals be pigtailed - including the one run from the GFCI to the downstream outlet (GFCI protected)?  Does the attached diagram look correct?  Should the neutral going to the GFCI protected outlet (off the GFCI) be pigtailed with the rest?  I excluded the ground wires from the diagram - they are all pigtailed together.

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Comment: Are you aware that it is a code violation to have lighting on a kitchen receptacle circuit?

Comment: Not even a multi-wire branch circuit?

Answer (score 4):

No, do not join all of the neutrals. The GFCI load terminals need the neutral to remain separate. Your diagram is correct in that respect.

However, kitchen outlets must be dedicated; the circuit may not be shared with lighting as you have in your diagram. This is almost certainly a code violation in any jurisdiction.

Comment: Guess I will have to run another line for the lights :(  Thanks for the feedback!  Is that code for just kitchen and bathrooms?

Comment: @chatman -- Kitchens require two dedicated, 20A small-appliance circuits as per 210.52(B); however, there is no requirement for a dedicated circuit for bathroom outlets in the 2014 NEC.

Comment: This is a stand alone receptacle above the counter top - no appliances on this circuit. More of a general purpose receptacle

Comment: @chatman -- do you have 2 dedicated 20A small-appliance branch circuits for your kitchen already?

Comment: Yes, There are already 2 dedicated 20A circuits.  This is on another outlet above the counter.

Comment: Oddly enough, I misread the Code here -- 210.11(C)(3) *does* require a dedicated circuit for bathroom receptacles (although it can be shared with bathroom lighting if it only feeds a single bathroom), and 210.52(B) states that the *two or more* small-appliance branch circuits that feed the kitchen outlets must feed *all* the kitchen outlets, and must not have any other outlets -- so you'll have to run the new circuit.  Sorry about the red herring!